# A good solution for await in try/catch/finally?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await, c#-5.0

I need to call an `async` method in a `catch` block before throwing again the exception (with its stack trace) like this :

```
try
{
    // Do something
}
catch
{
    // <- Clean things here with async methods
    throw;
}
```

But unfortunately you can't use `await` in a `catch` or `finally` block. I learned it's because the compiler doesn't have any way to go back in a `catch` block to execute what is after your `await` instruction or something like that...

I tried to use `Task.Wait()` to replace `await` and I got a deadlock. I searched on the Web how I could avoid this and found [this site](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/the-perfect-recipe-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-ending-up-with-a-deadlock-using-the-c-sharp-5-0-asynchronous-language-features).

Since I can't change the `async` methods nor do I know if they use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, I created these methods which take a `Func<Task>` that starts an async method once we are on a different thread (to avoid a deadlock) and waits for its completion:

```
public static void AwaitTaskSync(Func<Task> action)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await action().ConfigureAwait(false)).Wait();
}

public static TResult AwaitTaskSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> action)
{
    return Task.Run(async () => await action().ConfigureAwait(false)).Result;
}

public static void AwaitSync(Func<IAsyncAction> action)
{
    AwaitTaskSync(() => action().AsTask());
}

public static TResult AwaitSync<TResult>(Func<IAsyncOperation<TResult>> action)
{
    return AwaitTaskSync(() => action().AsTask());
}
```

So my questions is: Do you think this code is okay?

Of course, if you have some enhancements or know a better approach, I'm listening! :)

Comment: Using `await` in a catch block is actually allowed since C# 6.0 (see my answer below)

Comment: Related **C# 5.0** error messages: ***CS1985***: *Cannot await in the body of a catch clause.* ***CS1984***: *Cannot await in the body of a finally clause.*

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can move the logic outside of the `catch` block and rethrow the exception after, if needed, by using [`ExceptionDispatchInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo.aspx).

```cs
static async Task f()
{
    ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;
    try
    {
        await TaskThatFails();
    }
    catch (MyException ex)
    {
        capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
    }

    if (capturedException != null)
    {
        await ExceptionHandler();

        capturedException.Throw();
    }
}
```

This way, when the caller inspects the exception's `StackTrace` property, it still records where inside `TaskThatFails` it was thrown.

Comment: What is the advantage of keeping `ExceptionDispatchInfo` instead of `Exception` (as in the Stephen Cleary's answer)?

Comment: I can guess it's that if you decide to rethrow the `Exception`, you lose all the previous `StackTrace`?

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina Exactly.

Answer (score 57):

You should know that since C# 6.0, it's possible to use `await` in `catch` and `finally` blocks, so you could in fact do this:

```
try
{
    // Do something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    await DoCleanupAsync();
    throw;
}
```

The new C# 6.0 features, including the one I just mentioned [are listed here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation) or as a video [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2014/116).

Comment: Support for [await in catch/finally blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#C.23_6.0) in C# 6.0 is also indicated on Wikipedia.

Comment: @DavidRR. the Wikipedia is not authoritive. It is just another web site among millions as far as this is concerned.

Comment: While this is valid for C# 6, the question was tagged C# 5 from the very beginning. This makes me wonder if having this answer here is confusing, or if we should just remove the specific version tag in these cases.

Answer (score 16):

If you need to use `async` error handlers, I'd recommend something like this:

```
Exception exception = null;
try
{
  ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  exception = ex;
}

if (exception != null)
{
  ...
}
```

The problem with synchronously blocking on `async` code (regardless of what thread it's running on) is that you're synchronously blocking. In most scenarios, it's better to use `await`.

**Update:** Since you need to rethrow, you can use `ExceptionDispatchInfo`.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I know this method already. That's what I do normally, but I can't do this here. If I simply use `throw exception;` in the `if` statement the stack trace will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

We extracted [hvd's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16626313/258772) to the following reusable utility class in our project:

```
public static class TryWithAwaitInCatch
{
    public static async Task ExecuteAndHandleErrorAsync(Func<Task> actionAsync,
        Func<Exception, Task<bool>> errorHandlerAsync)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;
        try
        {
            await actionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
        }

        if (capturedException != null)
        {
            bool needsThrow = await errorHandlerAsync(capturedException.SourceException).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (needsThrow)
            {
                capturedException.Throw();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One would use it as follows:

```
    public async Task OnDoSomething()
    {
        await TryWithAwaitInCatch.ExecuteAndHandleErrorAsync(
            async () => await DoSomethingAsync(),
            async (ex) => { await ShowMessageAsync("Error: " + ex.Message); return false; }
        );
    }
```

Feel free to improve the naming, we kept it intentionally verbose. Note that there is no need to capture the context inside the wrapper as it is already captured in the call site, hence `ConfigureAwait(false)`.