# Looking for an elegant way to get around "Cannot await in the body of a finally clause"

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following function:

```
private async Task DoSomething(NamespaceConnectionInfo nci)
{
    var session = await m_sessionProvider.GetSessionAsync(nci);
    SomeLegacySynchronousCode(session);
    await m_sessionProvider.EndSessionAsync(session);
}
```

where `EndSessionAsync` logs and swallows any exception (like a good destructor).

The problem is that `SomeLegacySynchronousCode` may throw an exception and then the session leaks.

It is clear to me perfectly why the following code is illegal:

```
private async Task DoSomething(NamespaceConnectionInfo nci)
{
    var session = await m_sessionProvider.GetSessionAsync(nci);
    try
    {
        SomeLegacySynchronousCode(session);
    }
    finally
    {
        await m_sessionProvider.EndSessionAsync(session);
    }
}
```

So, I am looking for an alternative that would be both correct and elegant.

**Variant I**

```
private async Task DoSomething(NamespaceConnectionInfo nci)
{
    var session = await m_sessionProvider.GetSessionAsync(nci);
    Exception exc = null;
    try
    {
        SomeLegacySynchronousCode(session);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exc = e;
    }
    await m_sessionProvider.EndSessionAsync(session);
    if (exc != null)
    {
        // Wrap to preserve the original stack trace.
        throw new AggregateException(exc);
    }
}
```

**Variant II**

```
private Task DoSomething(NamespaceConnectionInfo nci)
{
    return m_sessionProvider.GetSessionAsync(nci).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Task result = null;
        try
        {
            SomeLegacySynchronousCode(t.Result);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (t.Exception == null)
            {
                result = m_sessionProvider.EndSessionAsync(t.Result);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }).Unwrap();
}
```

Neither are as elegant as the aforementioned illegal async/await version.

I am looking to improve over the two variants that I have proposed, because both are ugly, frankly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [commonly-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16626313/120955) appears to be similar to your Variation 1:

> You can move the logic outside of the catch block and rethrow the
>   exception after, if needed, by using ExceptionDispatchInfo.
>
> ```
> static async Task f()
> {
>     ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;
>     try
>     {
>         await TaskThatFails();
>     }
>     catch (MyException ex)
>     {
>         capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
>     }
>
>     if (capturedException != null)
>     {
>         await ExceptionHandler();
>
>         capturedException.Throw();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This way, when the caller inspects the exception's StackTrace
>   property, it still records where inside TaskThatFails it was thrown.

Comment: Missed that question. What is `ExceptionHandler` ? The ones I can see in MSDN are in `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher` and in `System.Reflection.Emit` namespaces. None seem to be relevant.

Comment: `ExceptionHandler()` is just a placeholder for your exception-handling logic. In your case, it would be `m_sessionProvider.EndSessionAsync(session);`