# prevent application crashes when sending data over a closed websocket connection

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

The ASP.NET Core application uses websocket connection on the client side and Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server 0.1.0 (latest stable version on nuget as I know) on the server side. The simple sending code is

```
await _ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(arrbr), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, ctk);
```

the problem is this line throws error when it is a closed connection. I would like that method to return a Boolean if process was successful. I already check if the connection is open like this:

```
_ws.State == WebSocketState.Open
```

But this does not work if user has 
unplugged the network cable or disconnected his device(almost all situations except closing the browsers).

As an extra, I do not know how to simulate network connection loss for one of two clients and *I suppose WebSocketState is readonly, please warn me if I am wrong* and I do not think shorter pings will solve this problem. 

I have two ideas:

1. I may use the sender code in a try catch block. (I am not comfortable with using try catch in production code)
2. I may set interval on the client side, and ask the server like "what is new for me". I feel bad with this because it is away from being a websocket(closer to http).

**Is there any way to fix this without using try catch?** I know that this is not a qualified question but a qualified problem for me. I can share full code if needed.

### Update 1

***after using server-side logging:***

While messaging is working well in production environment, I disconnect the client by unplugging the network cable and send data to the client. I use try catch and no catch. then i get **[this](https://github.com/aspnet/WebSockets/issues/63)** error.

This means I cant detect lost connection by using try catch. and i think i can solve this by handling this throw. 

How can I handle this error?

### update2

I have noticed that "Exceptions from an Async Void Method Can’t Be Caught with Catch" and "it's possible to use await in catch" since c# 6 **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626161/a-good-solution-for-await-in-try-catch-finally)** however I can not catch the throw.
 I may try running synchronously `await _ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(arrbr), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, ctk).runsynchronously();` if I cant fix in this way

### update3

running synchronously does not help. using try catch does not differ. as a result question, asp.net core websocket how to ping

### update4

my log file when using Microsoft.aspnetcore.websockets.server 0.1.0

`fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HL1940BSEV8O": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of stream
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<EnsureDataAvailableOrReadAsync>d__38.MoveNext()` 
my log file when using Microsoft.aspnetcore.websockets 1.0.0

`fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HL19H5R4CS21": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake. ---> System.IO.IOException: Error -4077 ECONNRESET connection reset by peer ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4077 ECONNRESET connection reset by peer`

Comment: Ugh, I am totally not into reading that block of text. If you want help, you will need to make it readable, like using paragraphs.

Comment: actually i don't know how to paragraph too :} i will learn it after learning how to send data over websockets

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Making newlines and capitalisation  isn't rocket science.

Comment: HAve you tried using a Try/Catch block ?

Comment: I tried trycatch too much. the problem occurs in server and only when the network cable has been unplugged. it works perfect locally. and I do not know how to simulate network loss locally

Comment: thank you. but I use aspnetcore websocket and it does not have a method named "poll".

Comment: It seems like this scenario is exactly what a try/catch block is intended to resolve. A network cable becoming unplugged is certainly *not* expected behavior, and a catch block should allow your application to recover. Without seeing more of your code it's not possible to debug any further.

Comment: here is my code. http://csharppad.com/gist/e02082789c2795da2777d2fcbb168d30  i gave up and decided to use try catch, but it does not solve the problem. it looks like something else causes the error but that does not. i know this because of the application works well except unplugging the cable

Answer (score 7):

I might be missing something, but why can't wrap the sending operation in a method that returns `bool` in the following manner:

```
private async Task<bool> DoSend()
{
    bool success = true;

    try
    {
        await _ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(arrbr), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, ctk);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Do some logging with ex
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}
```

I also suggest reading about [Async All The Way](https://www.google.co.il/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=UONWWLmhEsqP8Qfxs6PwCQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=Async%20All%20The%20way), it should clear some of the confusion with `async void`, `async Task` and `async Task<T>`

Comment: I tried once more like you did and no luck, it always returns true, never catches. I use like catch { success=false; } not catch (exception ex){ success=false;}  because of I do not need exception. I don't know if it matters. I will focus on "async all the way"

Comment: what type is _ws ?

Comment: what do you mean by type? it s an asp.net core application including "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server": "0.1.0"

Comment: @ergen if it never catches, application will not crash. So where is your application crashing exactly? Can you provide a callstack?

Comment: I updated with the error logs.  I am not sure about application crashes . if I send a message to the server after this error occurred, the client is closed and the server does not accept new socket connections until I recycle the application pool

Comment: additionally, here is full [class]. i can share more simplified version too but i do not think that is the problem. (http://csharppad.com/gist/e02082789c2795da2777d2fcbb168d30)

Comment: ah i can not edit my comment.sorry about it. line 87.  it works the same way even if i don't use try catch there.

Answer (score 0):

Until C# 6.0 to capture an exceptions from async methods you should use the [ExceptionDispatchInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo.aspx) type. Then the code will look like this:

```
private async Task<bool> DoSend()
{
    bool success = true;
    ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;

    try
    {
        await _ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(arrbr), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, ctk);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
    }

    if (capturedException != null)
    {
        await ExceptionHandler();

        if (needsThrow)
        {
            capturedException.Throw();
        }
    }

    success = capturedException == null;

    return success;
}
```

Comment: the problem is the code inside "catch" never works only "try". I can see that in log files. i think sendasync method thinks that sending is successful